# Does javascript have a method to replace part of a string without creating a new string?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var str = "This is a string";
var thing = str.replace("string","thing");

console.log( str )
>> "This is a string" 

console.log( thing )
>> "This is a thing"
```

Is there another method I can use, besides replace, that will alter the string in place without giving me a new string object?

Comment: I suggest you never use reserved words (such as `string`) when defining variable names in any language.

Comment: `string` is not a reserved word in JavaScript ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words)). However, `str` is `undefined`. You messed up the variable names!

Answer (score 116, accepted):

No, strings in JavaScript are immutable.

Comment: You could do something like this though if you don't want to create a new variable: `string = string.replace("string", "thing");`

Answer (score 16):

Not that i am aware of, however if the reason you want to do this is just to keep your code clean you can just assign the new string the the old variable:

```
var string = "This is a string";
string = string.replace("string", "thing");
```

Of course this will just make the code look a bit cleaner and still create a new string.

Answer (score 6):

There is a reason why strings are immutable. As Javascript use call-by-sharing technic, mutable string would be a problem in this case :

```
function thinger(str) {
    return str.replace("string", "thing");
}

var str = "This is a str";
var thing = thinger(str);
```

In this situation you want your string to be passed by value, but it is not. If str was mutable, thinger would change str, that would be a really strange effect.

Answer (score 2):

As [Cristian Sanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6192199/4791116) mentioned, in javascript strings are immutable.
Depending on the task we can try to work around with the following approaches:

```js
 // **fastest** .split(...).join(...)
var string = 'My string'
string = string.split('string').join('thing')
   console.info('with .split-.join', { string }) // 'My thing'

// **good old wine** .replace('...','...') as mentioned above
string = 'My string'
string = string.replace('string','thing')
   console.info('with .replace', { string }) // 'My thing'

// **ES6 string interpolation**
string = (arg) => `My ${arg}`
   console.info('with interpolation 1', { string: string('string') }) // 'My string'
   console.info('with interpolation 2', { string: string('thing') }) // 'My thing'
```

Note: there are fancy ways with such approaches as `..indexOf(...) and .substring(...)`, `.charAt(...)`,