# Why does the Javascript replace() function not do anything?

Tags: javascript

Here's my function:

```
CSS_Left = '450px';
CSS_Left.replace('px', '');
alert(CSS_Left);
```

It returns '450px'

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/D2Mgb/

I want it to replace 'px' with nothing.

Comment: Is it really so hard to google "javascript replace" and look at, well, nigh on any of the results? They will show the proper use of this method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does javascript have a method to replace part of a string without creating a new string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192169/does-javascript-have-a-method-to-replace-part-of-a-string-without-creating-a-new)

Comment: Better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) are immutable.

> All types except objects define immutable values. Specifically, strings are immutable (unlike in C for instance).

So, [`str.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns a new string. Try this instead:

```
CSS_Left = CSS_Left.replace('px', '');
```

Or if you don't want to overwrite the original string, just do it in the `alert` call

```
alert(CSS_Left.replace('px', ''));
```

---

It's worth noting that `.replace` can also take a regexp. Though it's not necessary in your case, you could do something like this to achieve the same result

```
CSS_Left = CSS_left.replace(/px$/, '');
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that X( . Thanks a lot! That was confusing me.

Comment: Moreover, String objects are immutable. You cannot edit them, only create modified new instances.

Comment: @LexLythius, I'll make a note. Thanks for your review.

Answer (score 3):

Because `.replace()` return a new string. If you want to update the old string you should write:
`CSS_Left = CSS_Left.replace('px', '');`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but the function replace() creates a new variable.
Try this :

```
var CSS_Left = '450px';
CSS_Left = CSS_Left.replace('px', '');
alert(CSS_Left);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output of the replace call needs to be reassigned to CSS_Left