# Javascript String replace "'"

Tags: javascript

How do I replace ' in javascript. For example I want to convert O'conor to O-conor.
This doesnt work. I am doing something stupid.

```
var dummyStr =  "O'conor";
dummyStr.replace("'","-");
console.log(dummyStr); //prints O'conor 
dummyStr.replace(/'/g,"-"); //still prints O'conor not O-conor
```

Please mark duplicate if this has already been asked elsewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the Javascript replace() function not do anything?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18647411/why-does-the-javascript-replace-function-not-do-anything)

Comment: you are doing right but you have to save value of `dummyStr.replace("'","-");` in varible, you can do like this `dummyStr = dummyStr.replace("'","-");`

Comment: exact duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433212/replace-method-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign a variable to the return value of `replace()`

e.g.

```
var dummyStr =  "O'conor";
var ammendedString = dummyStr.replace("'","-");
console.log(ammendedString );
```

Comment: feel like a moron! Thanks

Comment: No problems, it's easy to miss things like that, at a more fundamental level, try to remember that strings in JavaScript are immutable, so you can't 'change' them as such, you generally need to run functions against them and either assign the result to something else, or back to the original variable.

Answer (score 7):

`replace` (cf. [replace on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)) does not modify the current string. You have to assign it like this :

```
dummyStr = dummyStr.replace("'","-");
console.log(dummyStr); //prints O-conor
```

Comment: i feel like a moron! Thanks

Comment: No worry, that's a common issue :-)

Answer (score 3):

you just need to store this to some variable after replace, like below

```
dummyStr = dummyStr.replace("'","-");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
dummyStr = dummyStr.replace("'","-");
```

Btw for replacing all:
[Replace All - StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)