# Reverse a string function not working

Tags: javascript, string, debugging

This is my javascript code to reverse a string.

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 

    var left = 0
    var right = str.length;

    while (left<right)
    {
       var temp = str[left]
       str[left] = str[right-1]
       str[right-1] = temp

       left ++
       right -- 
    }

    return str;
}
```

I am confident that the logic of my program is correct as I have done it before on C++ before but for some reason, probably the way memory is allocated in javascript, FirstReverse returns the original string

Can some kind soul point out to me when I have went wrong and explained to me ??

Thanks

Comment: what does it return?

Comment: it returns the original string

Comment: I expect it throws an Error because the first reference to `str[right]` will be out of bounds

Comment: `str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Comment: @CD.. `reverse` is irrelevant here

Comment: doesn't look like you can modify strings in this way in JS: `s = 'hello'; s[2] = 'b'; console.log(s)` prints `hello`

Comment: In js, strings are immutable. So `str[left]` should not have any effect

Answer (score 1):

@CD.'s Comment:

```
str.split('').reverse().join('')
```

does what you want.
It splits  the string for every character as an array, reverses the order of the array and joins it back together as a string.

In your case:

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are pretty much immutable if you go down this road.

You should do one thing before manipulating this data, convert your string to an array, keep your manipulation going on the array (use the right variable names) and convert the array back to a string.

It could look something like this:

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    var left = 0
    var right = str.length;
    var buffer = str.split('');

    while (left<right)
    {
        var temp = buffer[left]
        buffer[left] = buffer[right]
        buffer[right] = temp

        left ++
        right -- 
    }
    return buffer.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot modify strings in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192169/does-javascript-have-a-method-to-replace-part-of-a-string-without-creating-a-new) in JavaScript. A simple different approach would be to start with an empty string and add characters right-to-left.

```
function reverse(str) {
  var newStr = '';
  for(var i = str.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    newStr += str[i]
  }
  return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here' is a fix that's close to your code:

```js
function FirstReverse(str) { 

    
    var right = str.length-1;
    var rev="";

    while (right>=0)
    {
       var temp = str[right]
       rev = rev+ temp;
       
       right -- 
    }

    return rev;
}

alert(FirstReverse("abcde"));
```

However, this is not an optimal implementation, but it should be understandable to you.

What we do is make a new blank string (rev) to hold the reverse.   The we find the last letter (str.length-1) and start adding it to the result(rev) string, and we decrease the position we're pulling from by 1 until we've gotten to the begining of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution. It starts at the last position of the string and counts backwards, adding to reversed string 1 character at a time.

```
function FirstReverse(str) { 
    var rstr=''; 
    for (var l=str.length;l>0;l--)
    {
      rstr+=str.substring(l-1,l)
    }
    return rstr;
}
// example:
FirstReverse('foobar'); // output: raboof
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in addition to posting code?